# Web Socket Connection Failed on Azure Server

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, websocket

I have created web socket server using Asp .Net Web Api C# and its working fine on my local. But after hosting to Azure server it showing error below.

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://mysite.azurewebsites.net/webapi/api/Chat' failed:

I have enabled the Web Socket Option on Azure App Configuration Section as well.

My Azure subscription is pay-as-you-go and App Service Plan is F1:Free.

Is there anything I have to change in settings?

Here is my Code :
client side:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var url = 'wss://mysite.azurewebsites.net/webapi/api/Chat';


alert('Connecting to: ' + url);

ws = new WebSocket(url);

ws.onopen = function() {

    alert('Connected');

    $('#mySendBtn').click(function() {

        ws.send($('#txtMessage').val());

        $('#txtMessage').val('');

    });

};

ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    //some code
};

$('#btnLeave').click(function() {

    ws.close();

});

ws.onclose = function() {

    alert('Closed <br/>');

};

ws.onerror = function(e) {

    alert('error');

};});
```

Server Side ref : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/618032/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-4-5-Part-2

Comment: this seems to be a problem with the handshake. Can you add your code?

Comment: I referred this url(https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/).They mentioned WebSockets Connection Limits .How to do that on Azure server?